# Call Session Attributes in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session

I currently have the following:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();         
String discountError = (String) session.getAttribute("discountError");

if (discountError.equals("true")){
    session.setAttribute("discountAdded", "false");
    forwardPage = "DiscountEnd.jsp";

}
else if (discountError.equals("false")){
    session.setAttribute("discountAdded", "true");
    forwardPage = "Confirm.jsp";                
}
```

`JSP`

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Discount(s) Added Successfully</title>
</head>

<body>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${discountAdded == 'true'}">
        <p align="center">  
            All Discount(s) added successfully!     
        </p>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${discountAdded == 'false'}">
        <p align="center">
            Error Found! No Discounts added!
        </p>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>

<br>
<form action='HotelOwnerController' method='POST' style="text-align:center">
    <input  type="submit" name="action" value="Back to Welcome Screen"/>
</form>
```

When I get to the `JSP` page, I am finding that the `discountAdded` `if` condition is not being evaluated.

Would someone know how I can read `session` attributes in a `JSP` page?

Comment: `${sessionScope.discountAdded eq 'true'}` or `${sessionScope['discountAdded'] eq 'true'}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the session attributes using sessionScope in your JSP.

So you need to call like this: `${sessionScope.discountAdded == 'true'}`

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.discountAdded == 'true'}">
        <p align="center">  
            All Discount(s) added successfully!     
        </p>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.discountAdded == 'false'}">
        <p align="center">
            Error Found! No Discounts added!
        </p>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

**Suggestion:**

If discountAdded is going to contain only boolean value, then instead of `<c:when>` conditions, use `<c:otherwise>` for the another condition.

```
 <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${sessionScope.discountAdded == 'true'}">
            <p align="center">  
                All Discount(s) added successfully!     
            </p>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <p align="center">
                Error Found! No Discounts added!
            </p>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for that moahamedrias. However, the first condition is still not being processed. If I set `discountAdded = false`, I go directly to the `JSP` page and everything seems to work. If I set `discountAdded = true`, then I first go to another `JSP` page and then to the one shown in my question. When this happens, the `discountAdded` doesn't seem to be processed.

Comment: Could you remove multiple conditions, and use <c:otherwise>
    </c:otherwise> for the alternative condition to check

Comment: Updated my answer, check it now

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. I realised I was invalidating the session just before I moved to the other `jsp` page. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, when session varialbles are catched in jsp page, it comes in "`Object`" data type. we have to parse them to String. For that we can use either `.toString()` method or we can cast it using

```
String str=(String)session.getAttribute("session_name");
```

OR

```
String str=(String)session.getAttribute("session_name");
```

For your code I suggest use `sessionScope`

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${sessionScope.discountAdded == 'true'}">
    <p align="center">  
        All Discount(s) added successfully!     
    </p>
</c:when>
<c:when test="${sessionScope.discountAdded == 'false'}">
    <p align="center">
        Error Found! No Discounts added!
    </p>
</c:when>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JSP we can access session variable as follows:

```
<%
String str=session.getAttribute("session_name");

%>
```

Comment: No, your answer is not verified. At least check it before suggesting here.